# Excitation and decay of electronic states to dark states

Tags: atomic-physics

I am interested in modeling the populations of low-lying, long-lived "dark" electronic states after excitation of an atom in the ground state with a laser. Using just a regular rate equation solver, I get nonsensical results. Provided there are no interactions between the low-lying states and the branching ratios to these states are known, is something like an Optical Bloch Equation solver needed to determine their population as the laser irradiates the atom?